# Do a total wipe of my device

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom-flashing, formatting

I have flashed my ROM several times with different ROMS, and sometimes back to stock. I flashed roms, modems, kernels etc.

But the flashing never seems to totally format the device, because the folders of old software keep showing up on the phones hard drive.

Is there a way to completely format my device, and install a new rom afterwards.

I have a Samsung Galaxy 2s running gingerbread 2.3

If this question is already ask this can be closed and redirected. I could not find a similair question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely format your device, you need to use Odin and an Odin-able ROM (preferably stock).  Note that the device can't be *blank*.  You should always have firmware on it.

1. Download Odin 1.85 from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?s=99b3b5d0c89da26121a24a015281ffe3&attachmentid=581913&d=1304094576) and extract it.
2. Download stock firmware (listed [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1075278)), you probably want [JPKF3](http://www.multiupload.com/L1M8VYMAH7).
3. Put your phone into Download mode (you may have to attempt this a couple times):

   1. Power off the phone
   2. Hold <kbd>VolDown</kbd>+<kbd>OK</kbd>:

      1. Click the <kbd>Power</kbd> button
      2. Let go of <kbd>VolDown</kbd>+<kbd>OK</kbd> when the Android icon with "Downloading..." underneath appears
4. Start Odin
5. Connect your phone to USB and ensures it shows up in Odin (a yellow box with a COM port will be shown).  If it doesn't, disconnect and reconnect.  If it still doesn't, reboot your phone and start over from (3).
6. Click the <kbd>PDA</kbd> button in Odin and choose the firmware file you downloaded.
7. Click <kbd>Start</kbd> and wait till "PASS" appears in the Message area.  If it fails, start over from (3).

Normally, to completely wipe the device, you would select "Re-partition" in Odin.  However, this apparently can brick the Galaxy S II! So don't do it.  I guess it only works consistently with the original Galaxy S.

Comment: This method does not clear the phones internal sdcard. This leaves the files that are on your phone. My question was not how to go back to stock rom. Only dialing *2767*3855# does a complete format of the internal sdcard. Im on the GT-i9100. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @Saif Why don't you clear the internal SD yourself? It's easy enough to delete all the files on it.

Comment: Are there no important files on there that won't be put back when you just delete everything?

Comment: @Saif Samsung's internal SD is meant to be treated the same as external SD cards in other phones. No important files are stored there. Just downloads, apps that you move to SD, possibly photos, etc.

Comment: OH! Sorry i did not know that as I am new to android. On WM6.5 the interneal storage was also the place where system files were stored.

Comment: @Saif No problem! Most Android phones have "internal storage" where the system files are, plus an external SD card.  Samsung has replaced the external SD card with internal SD storage, separate from the main internal storage, on several phones.  Some of them have external SD as well, which is barely used at all unless you are copying files back and forth from your device to another or a PC.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install recover (such as Amon-ra or Malez)?

In that case you can just reboot in recovery using the free application from the market "quick boot" and do from the recovery a Wipe ALL.

If not it's time to find out which kind of recovery is best for you (and your device) and install it

:)

ps
If you add further details and/or questions I can answer more accurately

Comment: I did not install the software you asked. I install a kernel version that has clockworkmod loaded. Then I boot into clockworkmod, wipe cashe partition, do factory reset, and then flash a new rom.

Comment: did you try to do the wipe (cache and data) 3 times in a row before flashing the new rom?

Comment: LOL no never 3 times, should you do that before everything goes away. I just one time would be enough. I'm gonna try it now, lets see if it helps.

Comment: NO, just flashed my stock rom again, after that wiped cache + data 3 times. Did a fresh boot into a new rom, still see folders like openfient, goweather, appiecache. All apps not default on the system, and also not installed on the new rom, still showing up from old instances.

Comment: :O that's black magic...
I've read on various forum of the "3 times" trick but have no experience with it personally.
I'll keep investigating

Comment: Thanks, but are the programs like Amon-ra, Marez, qiockboot, the same as clockworkmod. Or should I try one of those programs.

Comment: Hey this worked for me: Remove SIM and microSD cards, start the phone and enter *2767*3855# into the dialer. None of the programs that went into recovery mode. Really strange. Or maybe it had something to do with the external SD card, but i doubt it as it is completely empty.

Comment: Oh my god O_O

Anyway: horray to you for doing it! :D

Answer (score 0):

Boot in a custom recovery (cwm, twrp or anything similar) and format

/data, /cache, /system, /sdcard (or /emmc), /external-sdcard (or /sd-ext or anything like that)

now install with odin a stock rom and it's all back to like it was when you first got it