# Formatting (or reinstalling) Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-kies, system-freeze, formatting

I have some experience about Android phones (but i'm not an expert) .

I have problems with my Samsung Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100) . Its battery heating too much, there are a lots of applications, sometimes phone freezing and not responsing, it's battery consumption is too much and it's a little slow. And **sometimes restarting itself.**

In shortly, i'm using it for long time, i installed too many apps and uninstall some of them. Now i want to clear everything (except SD card datas) , delete all datas / apps . And start from origin, again. I'll my (really needed) applications from Google Play, later.

In computer knowledge, it's mean *format* , i think.

But for mobile phones, I'm not sure, it's called as "formatting" or "firmware reinstalling" .

I plugged my phone to computer and launch Samsung Kies but there isn't *reinstall firmware* option.

**Notes**

1. Android version : 4.0.3
2. My phone isn't rooted. (and i won't do that)
3. I'm worring about warranty. So, please just *legal* methods.
4. I don't want to lose my datas (music, etc) on my SD CARD.
5. I don't want to send my phone to technical service for this. It'll take at least 4-5 days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are most likely look for is called "factory reset". As the name suggests, a "factory reset" is supposed to reset the device to its original state, as it was delivered by the factory. What in fact is done by a factory reset is to wipe all user-installed apps and all user data (for the latter, except data stored on sdcard).

This can be done either from within the system menu (look for the entry with the "fence" symbol, it's labeled something with "Privacy") -- or using the hardware buttons, as described at [Hard-Reset.Com](http://www.hard-reset.com/samsung-i9100-galaxy-s2-hard-reset.html):

1. switch off your phone
2. press and hold <kbd>volume-up</kbd> and <kbd>home</kbd> buttons
3. press the <kbd>power</kbd> button for 2-3 seconds
4. release only <kbd>power</kbd> button, but KEEP pressing <kbd>Volume up</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> Buttons
5. with <kbd>Volume down</kbd> select *wipe data/factory reset* (3rd) > Press <kbd>Power</kbd>

There's no need to re-install any firmware. The system resides on its own (read-only) partition, which is not touched by this process. Having followed above steps, your phone should then boot in a clean state. Don't worry if the first boot after that takes a bit longer -- that is fully normal. Also this does not void your warranty, as these steps would also be recommended by the service hotline if your device went nuts, and they want to eliminate the cause of misconfiguration or misbehaving (user-installed) apps.

For a reference, you might also want to take a look at the question [Do a total wipe of my device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11365/do-a-total-wipe-of-my-device).

Comment: This won't touch to my external SD CARD , right ? Should i remove it before formatting?

Comment: It should not touch your SD card, that's right. It might do so for Apps2SD data (i.e. apps you installed on/moved to your SD card using the Apps2SD feature). To be sure, you could of course remove your SD card before doing the factory reset. In case you had some apps moved to the card, you might need to remove them manually (mount the card to your PC, and remove the `.android_secure` folder) to avoid problems when you try to re-install them.